# React.js - error when try to authorize with firebase gmail token

Tags: reactjs, firebase, axios, gmail

In react I use firebase Gmail login. Then I save the Gmail token, userId. And try to use the token when I post some values. but always I got an error. I don't understand how to verify this token.

```
export const inputIn = (data, token) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .post("https://auth-by-f038f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/AllInputes.json?auth" + token , data)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(inputSuccess(response.data.name, data));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error: ", err);
      });
    
  };
};
```

rules in firebase:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "AllInputes":{
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
        ".indexOn": ["userId"]
      }
  }
}
```

errors:

```
xhr.js:177 POST https://auth-b....com/AllInputes.json?authya29.A0Af... 401 (Unauthorized)

error:  Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

Comment: How is `token` initialized?

Comment: var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((result) => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", result.credential.accessToken);
        localStorage.setItem("userId", result.user.uid);

I used firebase Gmail for sign-in. I save the token in localStorage then used it for post values.

Comment: https://github.com/Forhadx/Login-by-Gmail.git  (this is my full code Github link). Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are missing an "=" in the request that you are sending.

> .post("https://auth-by-f038f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/AllInputes.json?auth" + token , data)

change it to

> .post("https://auth-by-f038f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/AllInputes.json?auth=" + token , data)